# Is the U.S. 90th in the world in terms of women in national legislatures?

Tags: united-states, sexism

The [Miss Representation Extended Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5pM1fW6hNs) makes the claim, at 6:03:

> The U.S. is the 90th in the world in terms of women in national legislatures.

The voice-over adds:

> If people knew that Cuba, China, Iraq and Afghanistan have more women in government than the United States of America, that would get some people upset. -- Gavin Newsom, Lt. Gov, California

The on-screen stat and the voice over at minimum don't seem to really correlate to each other, as "in-government" could potentially mean anything including the cleaning staff at a government-owned gas station.

Is this claim that the U.S. is ranked 90th in the world in terms of women in national legislatures true? And if so, what does it actually mean--what metric is it measuring?

Comment: Of course, seeing how a lot of the countries in the top of that list have a completely impotent legislature (being a woman in Parlament in Belorus is sorta the same power as you get from being on PTA in USA), these stats are kinda meaningless.

Comment: Add in countries where members of the House are selected by Ruling Elite instead of by citizens (Russia is a great example where a bunch of pretty celebrity women are chosen by Kremlin to popularize the party in power).

Comment: Everyone, please refrain from posting off-topic political comments.

Comment: Why would that be a surprise? After all, 19th Amendment was ratified by all states only in **1984**.

Comment: @DVK: If we disregard impotent legislatures, and e.g. only compare the US to Western Europe, the US narrowly beats *two* countries, and when we count both houses together, the US is only ahead of San Marino. Thus, the absolute ranking of the US might improve, but the relative ranking is still pretty bad.

Comment: @DVK: I've updated my answer to try and address your concerns.

Comment: @Jonas - +1. What would be REALLY interesting is to see how this relates statistically (e.g. are all EU countries #5-22 within 1-2% of each other or is there a qualitative/statistically significant gap

Comment: @Jonas - second concern - are the #s normalized for demographics? I don't know if there's a major discrepancy there between US and EU, but IIRC Russia has a much higher F/Mr ratio (due to significantly lower male life expectancy) in target demographics

Comment: @DVK: No, the numbers are not normalized for demographics. However, the deviations are usually with [10%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_sex_ratio) of the US, which would have an effect of ~0.2%, and thus not make a difference.

Comment: @DVK: The lower 2/3rd of EU countries are indeed from +5% to -10% around the US, and the US places a bit below the middle. So you could argue that the US is close to the median of the bad EU countries. See my edit.

Comment: @Fabian, the comments may be political but are not necessarily off-topic. The question assumes there is some desirable level of "women in national legislature" and also that there is some way of measuring it (the question explicitly asks about this). Both of these assertions are political assertions.

Comment: @Brian You're not seeing the comments I already deleted, the comment wasn't meant to say that *all* political comments are off-topic.

Comment: @Fabian - to be honest I also assumed you were referring to my comments. You may want to clarify whether you meant them to aviod confusion (if you as a mod have edit ability on your own old comments)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The claim is **true** within reasonable rounding margin.

According to the [Inter-Parliamentary Union](http://www.ipu.org/english/whatipu.htm), the US House of Representatives has the [69th-most women among all lower houses](http://www.ipu.org/wmn-e/classif.htm). In terms of ranking among nations, **the US is ranked 89th in terms of female members of (lower) houses out of 188 countries**. The US is also **ranked behind    Cuba (5th), China (51th), Iraq (35th) and Afghanistan (30th)**. Thus, the claim appears to be true.

*Shouldn't we compare members in both houses, rather than just compare lower houses?*

Well,  **if both houses were counted together, where applicable, the US would actually *lose* 8 ranks**: Barbados, Antigua and Barbuda, St. Lucia, Bahamas, Grenada, Swaziland, Ireland, and Zimbabwe all would get more than 17% representation.

*Shouldn't we compare the US to something more relevant than, say, Bhutan, or to places were parliaments have any relevance, unlike e.g. Belarus?*

- **Compared to its direct neighbours, the US comes in third out of three.** Mexico is #35 and Canada #41, when ties are counted as ranks (I didn't correct for combined houses).
- **Compared to the EU, the US comes in 21th out of 27+1**. The US beats 6 out of the 27 member states if women in both houses are counted: Slovenia, Slovakia, Romania, Malta, Hungary, and Cyprus.
- Just for fun: **Compared to the Arab League, the US comes in 8th out of 21+1**. Almost top third! Note that I didn't count Palestine, so there are 21 instead of 22 members. Honestly, I expected the US to do better here.

As an aside, [this report compiled for the parliament of Canada](http://www.parl.gc.ca/content/lop/researchpublications/prb0562-e.htm) mentions how election procedures can help or hurt women (and other underrepresented groups):

> Canada’s electoral system is a “single-member plurality” or “first-past-the-post” system. In every federal electoral district, the candidate with the most votes wins a seat in the House of Commons and represents that riding as its Member of Parliament. It has been argued that this system tends to discourage the election of women and other under-represented groups.

**BONUS TIME**

Here's the distribution of everybody, and the EU:

[image]

If we split the EU into three groups (low, medium, high percentage of women in legislatures), then they're topping the bottom half of the low group. Really, **in whichever way you turn this, the US looks bad** - unless the US strives to be totally average (i.e on the level of Venezuela and Turkmenistan; also, I mean median here) in terms of representation of women in legislatures.

Comment: Interesting... and if you count the 18 ties that happen between 1st and 69th place, that bumps the U.S. to 88th place... which is a more accurate way of calculating ranks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it makes no sense whatsoever *not* to count ties as multiple ranks. If there are two first places then the runner up has the third place.  Indeed, if there are two gold medals then consequently there is no silver medal, only bronze. (Good answer though.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It make sense not to count ties if you focus on *how many women* there are, rather than on the ranking of countries. You will have the second most women in legislatures regardless of how many countries share the honor of having most women in legislatures.

Comment: @Jonas If there are 88 countries (or whatever) with more women than you, you are 89th no matter how many ties. Any other answer strains the natural interpretation of the language.

Comment: @matt_black: If the 88 countries all have the same amount of women, then you still have the second most amount women in parliament. I agree, though, that if we are to rank the nations according to awesomeness, not counting ties is misleading (similarly, I find it problematic that they don't count women in both houses, but hey, both of the decision *help* the US - even though it doesn't fund the IPU! Japan pays most, i.e. 11%).

Comment: Jonas, you've gone well above and beyond the call of duty here... when this question is eligible, I think I may open a bounty so I can give you due credit :)

Comment: @Jonas Nobody in their right minds says that you have the second most women in parliament, just because the 88 countries ahead of you all happen to have the same number. Anyway, since its *fractions* of women there are no exact ties.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I guess that would depend whether they want to make themselves look better than they are :). Also, there are exact ties, 13 with 2, 3 or 5 equal fractions, respectively, for combined houses.